# How to transfer Pokemon Go (using an Apple account) from iPhone to an Android phone?

Tags: pokemon-go, ios

My best friend has an old iPhone 5 she use to play pokemon on. For Christmas I bought her an android so she can play again but we don't know how to move her account over. Other words old iPhone to new android.

Comment: Not a duplication.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how your question differs from the other one?

Comment: I agree with RaiderofCookie as this question is from Apple phone to Android, not Android to Android like that other question. @Wrigglenite

Comment: It's different because an apple account is used with the iPhone, which is not an option with the android phone. Only had a Facebook/email/Pokemon trainer club account been used, then the answers would be completely identical to the other thread.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how she created her account.
Sadly, if it wasn't through her email or Facebook or Pokémon account, but through her Apple ID, you can't. If it was through the other ways, all she would have to do is normally log in with Facebook/email/Pokémon trainer club account.

Answer (score 1):

Just open Pokémon go settings on iPhone, CONNECT the account to Facebook and on Android, sign in via Facebook. I don't know other way.